# How to install homebrew manually

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am trying to install homebrew manually. Homebrew works but I have problems with symlinks.

What I have done:

1. cd into `/usr/local`
2. execute `mkdir homebrew && curl -L
   https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip
   1 -C homebrew`
3. execute `usr/local/homebrew/bin/brew install wget`

The problem is that there are no symlinks for what homebrew installs. The `brew` command can not be found in the terminal either. Homebrew lives under `/usr/local/homebrew`

Comment: Why didn't you used the one liner install?

Comment: @Thomas have been struggling with that since it keeps "hanging" during installation without errors.

Comment: It hangs for me too. How I found this question. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must configure the `PATH` for OS X in order to find Homebrew.
That is, you must edit the `bash_profile` file by adding the following line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/homebrew:$PATH
```

Restart the Terminal session and try again.

Comment: Thanks, figured it had to be something with the Path